# Using public boolean add(Object new) {

Tags: java, eclipse

In my program I have two private variable

```
private Object[] array;
private int place;
```

I have initialized these variables in the constructor

```
public Arrays() {
        array = new Object[10];
        place = 0;
}
```

I am trying to properly implement the following method, this is what I have so far

```
public boolean add(Object new) {    

        for(int j = place+1; j <= 0; j++){
            array[j] = new;
        }
        
        place++;
        return true;    
}
```

I am having trouble with placing the object 'new' into the next unoccupied cell

Comment: You shouldn't use a for loop. Instead, best to simply have `array[place] = myParameter;` then `place++;` (don't use `new` as a parameter name since it is a reserved key-word.

Comment: Better still, use an ArrayList, *not* an array.

Comment: The duplicate in fact has similar code to anoniossss's answer

Comment: Adding to what @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested: 1) You're limiting the size of the array to 10 elements. 2) The method add, once corrected, will always append the element without letting you choose the place. 3) As soon as you try to add the 11th element you will get an OutOfBoundException. 4) I guess you meant `vals` to be `array` as for your declaration

Answer (score 1):

Just assign to the next free slot. `new` is a reserved keyword.

```
public boolean add(Object newItem) {    
       vals[place++]=newItem;
       return true;    
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it! The keyword **new** is used to assign a, well, new instance. The name **new** for a variable/object/etc is like telling your program, "Hey, this is my friend named"...they will keep waiting for you to tell them their darn name!

Comment: Watch out for when the `add` method will be called the 11th time.

Comment: And that is a story for another time ;)